# Form no longer entering into CiviMember for free memberships

Tags: civimember, contacts, contribution-page, 4.7

**CMS**: WordPress 4.4.2

**CiviCRM**: 4.7.1

After upgrading from 4.6.6 to 4.7.1, when someone submits our contribution form for a free membership, the membership is not recorded in the contact record nor in the CiviMember area.

The contact makes it in the Contacts area and database OK but wondering why the connection to CiviMember was severed. We can manually attach a membership to the contact fine, but long-term this is not a solution.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** What's worse is that these contacts have no record of their "contribution" (they came from a contribution form). So, they aren't displaying in "Find Contributions" either. Our memberships are free, so there is no paid transaction happening.

Comment: Are you able to mimic your problem here? http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Comment: @Catorghans Yes, wow! I filled out the member form, but the members aren't being recognized. They are simply being recorded as contacts. However, I can at least see that a contribution was made under their contact record. Now what? Is this a bug?

http://cl.ly/3n032S2G121E

Comment: can you link to the record you created?

Comment: this one perhaps http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fview&reset=1&cid=205

Comment: yes, that's the record! Think I should submit this as a bug? I don't know what else to do. *Edit* disregard this comment- I see your other comment below.

Comment: I'm having this problem as well, i think it must be a bug. I'm on 4.7.2 and Wordpress 4.4.2

Comment: might help if either Frank or Alison do a quick screencast showing the membership type set up, contribution page set up, and then the anon user filling in form and as the Contribution and Membership tab on the new contact

Comment: @Frank do you offer free memberships as well?

Comment: I apologize for posting this as an answer. I do not have the reputation to post a comment. I am using a form with free membership. The main purpose is so someone else in the organization has a simple way of adding contacts and membership from a form.

Comment: I'm using a form for free membership too. I'll see if I can't create the screen cast to show how I have the page setup.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I setup the scenario on the sandbox site with free membership. I'm experiencing the same issue there, contact is going in, but not recording the source or any memberships on the record - http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fview&reset=1&cid=207&key=6f2864fb86890dd1bf19ee6f183a5eda_9439&context=search

Comment: I setup the free membership scenario on the official sandbox demo. I was able to duplicate the problem so this may very well be a glaring bug and not something wrong with our configurations. Stay tuned...

Comment: you are right that that was not something that i included in the test. good catch. if you are certain then worth adding in to JIRA  https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/login.jsp and add your own answer and gain some more cred. well done.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem in your demo example is that you did it as a Test, which therefore doesn't show. If you go to Find Members, and set 'is test' to YES I then see the membership for a-test f-test if that is your example

also i did it for user = demo and did a 'pay later' option and that fired through fine.

so this may not be an answer to your original question but does answer your 'this is wrong on demo too' i believe.

Comment: you're right, I see it in the demo under the search "is test". It does answer the demo question, but now I'm wondering what could possibly be wrong with my configuration that it wouldn't appear under memberships at all. I even tried making a new contribution form for membership but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a glaring issue with CiviCRM's latest 4.7 release. I have posted this as a critical bug on CiviCRM's issue tracker here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18071

Per the comments in my question, I was able to reproduce this issue on CiviCRM's official sandbox installation.